# What does this flat symbol over a turn mean?

Tags: notation, accidentals, ornaments

[image]

I think it means for the starting note to be lowered one semitone, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11):

Accidental written above the turn symbol affects the upper note of the turn (which indeed is the first one for a regular turn), so (assuming the key of C major an no accidentals earlier in this measure) instead of playing D-C-B-C, one should play **Db**-C-B-C.

Accidental below the turn symbol would affect the lower (third) note of the turn.

Comment: I was puzzling over how this would sound when I remembered that the OP hasn't included a key signature in the screenshot. It's much easier to imagine if there's a Bb and Eb.

Comment: @AndyBonner You are probably right, but the chromatic turn resolving all the way up to E natural harkens back to an age of classical music where Europeans were emulating 'Turkish' music.