# Playing gruppetto with accidentals

Tags: accidentals, ornaments

I am playing the Chopin's *Prélude in E minor*, Op. 28 No. 4, and I wonder how I should play the following gruppetto.

[image: A measure of piano music with the key signature of one sharp. There is an A with a sharp accidental, then another A (sharp) followed by a G in the octave above. Between this second A (sharp) and the G, there is Gruppetto symbol with a double sharp sign below it.]

Notice that the A note is already sharp.
Much appreciate your explanations!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "x" underneath the turn symbol indicates that the lower note should be made a double sharp. Thus, the turn is played B-A#-Gx-A#.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron, I am seeing here https://youtu.be/CU9RgI9j7Do?si=M_Uim7cXJcsGJo8D&t=106 that an additional A is added at the beginning.
A-A#-Gx (= G## = A, thank you for that, that was my doubt) -A#

Comment: @JuanChô for completeness, you can also see in [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/132665/what-does-this-flat-symbol-over-a-turn-mean) that, similarly, an accidental _above_ the turn symbol affects the highest note of the turn (i.e., its first note).

Comment: Why is the turn sign *in between* dots rather than *over* the note to which it refers?

Comment: @Tim to make clear that it is used in transitioning from to A# up to the G.

Comment: So, if the sign was above the A#, what else could it possibly mean?

Comment: @Tim "if the sign was above the A#..." Which sign?  The accidental's position relative to the ornament sign is the thing that tells you which note it refers to.  The fact that the accidental is below the ornament means that it refers to the note below the note to which the ornament is applied.  The ornament is applied to the A sharp, so the double sharp below the ornament applies to the G sharp, altering it to G double sharp.  The horizontal positioning of the ornament sign indicates that the ornament comes at the end of the beat rather than at the beginning.

Comment: @JuanChô there's no A natural here, only G double sharp.